# How to use UIStepper to put integer in to a text field with swift

Tags: swift, uistepper

How Can I use Swift to put integer in textfield from UIStepper?

this is how I did it in Objective C:

```
- (IBAction)oneClicker:(UIStepper *)sender {
    self.oneValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",
                          [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:[(UIStepper *)sender value]] intValue]];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_PlaySound);
}
```

Answer (score 15):

It's simple

```
@IBOutlet weak var oneValue: UITextField!

@IBAction func oneClicker(sender: UIStepper) {
    self.oneValue.text = Int(sender.value).description
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I got it to work don't know if the best way but here it is

```
  @IBOutlet weak var oneClicker: UIStepper!

 @IBAction func oneClicker(sender: UIStepper) {
    oneValue.text =  "\(Int(oneClicker.value))"
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

While trying above, got an error. Tried something different and it worked.

```
@IBOutlet var quantity: UILabel!    
@IBOutlet var StepCounter: UIStepper!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    StepCounter.autorepeat = true
    StepCounter.maximumValue = 10.0
    StepCounter.minimumValue = 1.0
    println(StepCounter.value)
    quantity.text = "\(Int(StepCounter.value))"
    StepCounter.addTarget(self, action: "stepperValueDidChange:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

}

func stepperValueDidChange(stepper: UIStepper) {

    let stepperMapping: [UIStepper: UILabel] = [StepCounter: quantity]

    stepperMapping[stepper]!.text = "\(Int(stepper.value))"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var splitNumLabel: UILabel!

@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(_ sender: UIStepper) {
    splitNumLabel.text = String(Int(sender.value))
}
```